# how to use localtime_s with a pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, localtime

I am working with a function in C++ to help get the integer for the month. I did some searching and found one that uses localtime but I do not want to set it up to remove warnings so I need to use `localtime_s`. but when I use that my pointer no longer works and I need someone to help me find what I am missing with the pointer.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "FolderTask.h"
#include <ctime> //used for getMonth
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int getMonth()
{
    struct tm newtime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime_s(&newtime,&now);
    int Month = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
    return Month;
}
```

the error I am getting is:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'errno_t' to 'tm *'
>   note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires
>   reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And are you using the Windows [`localtime_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx) function, or the [`localtime_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) from the C standard library? Those two are different. Please elaborate on the problems you have, please show us the possible error messages you get when you build. *Elaborate!*

Comment: So it's the [Windows Visual Studio extension `localtime_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx) you use. Read the reference, check and read about what the function returns,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like you're using Visual C++, so `localtime_s(&newtime,&now);` fills in the `newtime` struct with the numbers you want.  Unlike the regular `localtime` function, `localtime_s` returns an error code.

So this is a fixed version of the function:

```
int getMonth()
{
    struct tm newtime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    localtime_s(&newtime,&now);
    int Month = 1 + newtime.tm_mon;
    return Month;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was what i needed. I didn't relies that the pointer with the needed information became newtime and couldn't understand that.

Comment: If you're ignoring the error result though, you might as well not bother with the `_s` version.

Comment: The non-_s version returns a pointer to a C-runtime static buffer, which is sort of crappy.  But, Kevin's main reason for using it was to get rid of MSVC's deprecation warning without fussing with the `_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` definition.  And anyway, the only error condition localtime_s ever returns is EINVAL (invalid argument) -- so the user has to pass crap arguments to see this -- you won't get an error condition because the runtime or OS surprised you with something outside of your control, like a low memory condition or something.

Comment: Agreed in principle, but I've seen too often compiler warnings about unsafe methods (regardless of whether MS is right to label `localtime` as such) suppressed in a way that keeps the code equally unsafe, but makes it pretty much impossible for static analysis to detect it as unsafe. I consider that a very dangerous practice worth warning about.

Comment: Very helpful--I didn't realize initially that localtime_s and gmtime_s were so diffreent from their localtime/gmtime counterparts.